# Durandel at browser chrome, not arrive ro compositionComplete

Tags: google-chrome, web, durandal

I work in durandal project.

I have a problem:
In one of my pages, at browser chrome, it doesn't arrive to compositionComplete.
(I checked it by debug.)
In explorer- it arrives.

What can be the reasons?
What do I have to check?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a viewModel like this to inspect the binging:

```
/***==========LIFECIRCLE===============***/

    var canActivate = function canActivate(view, parent) {
        logger.log('Lifecycle : canActivate : Dashboard');
        return true;
    },

    activate = function activate(view, parent) {
        logger.log(viewmodel.title + ' View Activated', null, viewmodel.title, true);
        return true;
    },

    binding = function binding(view, parent) {
        logger.log('Lifecycle : binding : Dashboard');
        return { cacheViews: false }; //cancels view caching for this module, allowing the triggering of the detached callback
    },

    bindingComplete = function bindingComplete(view, parent) {
        logger.log('Lifecycle : bindingComplete : Dashboard');
    },

    attached = function attached(view, parent) {
        logger.log('Lifecycle : attached : Dashboard');
    },

    compositionComplete = function compositionComplete(view, parent) {
        logger.log('Lifecycle : compositionComplete : Dashboard');
    },

    canDeactivate = function canDeactivate(view, parent) {
        logger.log('Lifecycle : canDeactivate : Dashboard');
        return true;
    },

    deactivate = function deactivate(view, parent) {
        logger.log('Lifecycle : deactivate : Dashboard');
    },

    detached = function detached(view, parent) {
        logger.log('Lifecycle : detached : Dashboard');
    };

    /***==========VIEWMODEL===============***/

    var viewmodel = {
        title: 'Dashboard for inspection',
        canActivate: canActivate,
        activate: activate,
        binding: binding,
        bindingComplete: bindingComplete,
        attached: attached,
        compositionComplete: compositionComplete,
        canDeactivate: canDeactivate,
        deactivate: deactivate,
        detached: detached
    }//-->end of ViewModel

    return viewmodel;
```